# Interacting with web service from PHP

Tags: php, coldfusion

I would like to use SMS service on another server.

The URL for sending SMS is

`http://www.abcd.in/test/SMSService.cfc?method=SendSMS&Message=msg&mobno=982545331&AppID=lrs-ESID`

I want to use this URL  from within PHP script. I do not know how to do it. Please Help

Comment: If the web service was written in php, would you know how to do it?

Comment: Yes I know how to use POST and GET methods in php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you just need to call that url with parameters. There's couple of ways to do it. One of them is to use the [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) function, other - to use [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Here are some examples how to do it: http://www.blogs.zeenor.com/it/how-to-call-the-web-services-through-php.html